# Como descobrir que programa que rodando em primeiro plano no windows, preferência em python

Tags: python

Olá, preciso criar um contador de tempo que conte apenas quando o pycharm estiver aberto em primeiro plano, e outros programas. Como sei qual tela está sendo usada em primeiro plano no Windows? Eu quero fazer em python. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Este código mostra quem está sendo executado, ele é um loop mas serve de exemplo:

```
import win32gui
import time
import psutil
import win32process

i = 0

while i <= 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    w = win32gui
    w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
    pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(w.GetForegroundWindow())
    print(psutil.Process(pid[-1]).name())
```

Daí pra frente você pode implementar sua regra de negócios em cima deste código.